# PHQL DELETE Not Working?

Tags: html, phalcon

I am trying to use phalcons query language(PHQL) to remove items from a database, i have used the GET method obtain the id of the item clicked on.. The id is embedded

**Controller**:

```
public function deleteSkillsAction(){
        $id=$_GET["id"]
        $phql = "DELETE FROM Skills WHERE id =:id:";
        $manager->executeQuery(
        $phql,
        array(
            'id' => $id
            
        )
    );
    
}
```

Getting the following error message, and query is not going through:

> **Notice:** Undefined variable: manager in C:\xampp\htdocs\Blueware\app\controller\skillsController.php on line 15
>
> > **Fatal error:** Call to a member function executeQuery() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Blueware\app\controller\skillsController.php on line 15

Comment: change to `$phql = "DELETE FROM Skills WHERE id =:id";` It `id = :id` not `id =:id:`

Comment: I think that in Phalcon PHQL there is `:id:` not `:id`.

Comment: the phalcon docs specifies with a double colon [here](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/phql.html#deleting-data)

Comment: Try initialize `$manager = $this->modelsManager;`

Comment: @JoshBoiskin If it solves the problem, approve the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

first initialize the $manager variable, as per documentation,

```
$manager = $this->modelsManager;
$manager->executeQuery(
        $phql,
        array(
            'id' => $id

        )
    );
```

or

call is as

```
$this->modelsManager->executeQuery(
            $phql,
            array(
                'id' => $id

            )
        );
```